# tree view Hierarchy is not working properly in side the Update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, treeview, updatepanel

I am using a Tree View Hierarchy inside the `UpdatePanel`.  The ASP.NET code is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TreeView ID="HierarchyTreeView" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="HierarchyTreeViewResource1" EnableViewState="true"></asp:TreeView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and on code behind i am writing

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
        base.OnInit(e);
        HierarchyTreeView.PathSeparator = CaseListPresenter.PathSeparator;
        HierarchyTreeView.TreeNodePopulate += new TreeNodeEventHandler(HierarchyTreeView_TreeNodePopulate);
        HierarchyTreeView.SelectedNodeChanged += delegate {
            Presenter.CancelChangeFlag(); 
            Presenter.SelectedNodeChanged(); 
            CheckPreview(); 
        };
}
```

If I am using `TreeView` outside the `UpdatePanel` my `OnInit` is working well.  But, if I am using `TreeView` inside the `UpdatePanel`, it is not working properly. I want to maintain the scroll position of my tree view

Comment: Someone plz help me in this prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now finally i got the solution with this..

[Maintain Panel Scroll Position On Partial Postback ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288682/maintain-panel-scroll-position-on-partial-postback-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

TreeView is not fully supportive with update panel.

we can maintain the scroll position by using following script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         var IsPostBack = '<%=IsPostBack.ToString() %>';
         window.onload = function() {
             var strCook = document.cookie;
             if (strCook.indexOf("!~") != 0) {
                 var intS = strCook.indexOf("!~");
                 var intE = strCook.indexOf("~!");
                 var strPos = strCook.substring(intS + 2, intE);
                 if (IsPostBack == 'True') {
                     document.getElementById("<%=Panel4.ClientID %>").scrollTop = strPos;
                 }
                 else {
                     document.cookie = "yPos=!~0~!";
                 }
             }
         }
         function SetDivPosition() {
             var intY = document.getElementById("<%=Panel4.ClientID %>").scrollTop;
             document.title = intY;
             document.cookie = "yPos=!~" + intY + "~!";
         }  

</script>
```

call the `setDivPosition()` on ur Panel4

Comment: This script is working fine, but the whole browser scroll is not in control. if data is so long then it is first scrolling top then its coming to bottom (on the old position)