# GridView back to top after select specific row

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am using an `asp:GridView` with scrolling.

When I highlight a specific row, the `GridView` jumps back to the top.

I tried setting `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` inside `<%@ Page %>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288682/maintain-panel-scroll-position-on-partial-postback-asp-net

Comment: Code inside this link doesn't work , 
Any Ideas ?!