# Why does the grid-row position go to the bottom of the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have multiple user controls with gridviews inside. The issue is whenever I scroll past the height of the window and click on edit for a row, the row being edited goes to the bottom of the page. I would like  the page to maintain the scroll position wherever it was clicked.

The generic structure I have: *default page > update panel > mulitview > view1 > user control1 > gridview*

---

I have tried to add `maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true` to the default page but doesn't make a difference.

I have also tried to add an Update Panel around the gridview inside the user control but it won't detect the `<AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="EditButton">` because the edit button is inside a Template Field.

Is there a way to keep the edit row in the same position where it was clicked? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue thanks to the related questions on the right:

[How to maintain scroll position of a page when add dynamic rows in GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49255970/how-to-maintain-scroll-position-of-a-page-when-add-dynamic-rows-in-gridview?rq=1)

I had focus() on a textbox in edit mode...when I removed that, the scroll position stayed the same.