# Javascript $(window).scrollTop with PageRequestManager doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've some problem when I want to scroll after postback with asp.net.
if I try like this, it doesn't work but when I add an `alert(posYDoc)` before `$(window).scrollTop(yPosDoc)` in `EndRequestHandler` it's working perfectly and position in alert is ok.

```
    var yPosDoc;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        yPosDoc = $(window).scrollTop();
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $(window).scrollTop(yPosDoc);
    }
```

Anyone can help me ?
Thank you !

Comment: You should state your question a bit more clearly. Instead of just saying "I have a problem" and "it doesn't work," state what it is you are trying to achieve and what specifically is happening when you try the code you posted.

Comment: Put an alert into BeginRequestHandler and EndRequestHandler to display the values of yPosDoc. Check if it is the same and not 0 in both occasions.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616210/reset-scroll-position-after-async-postback-asp-net

Comment: When i use alert(yPosDoc) just before $(window).scrollTop(yPosDoc); it's working but when alert is not here $(window).scrollTop(yPosDoc); not works.